# iOS: What restrictions are there on data gathering from within an app?

Tags: ios

I have an app that I did as a proof of concept and put on the app store just to gain experience going through the process but it turns out, it gets quite a few downloads, probably 30 a week. No Angry Birds but the app is very specific on the data it provides. It's a free app and what I would like to do now is gather some data on the users - how often they use it, where they are, what information they are searching and saving. I have no intention of touching personal data but I'd like to be able to aggregate what all the users are doing and see if there's any value in that.

Is this permitted in an iOS app? I see reports where apps are gathering more data than that (like Path pulling all your contacts) and I would think what I am looking to do is pretty standard.

Any advice is appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check the App Store approval guidelines. That is the best resource you have.
https://developer.apple.com/appstore/resources/approval/guidelines.html

A few excerpts that may be relevant to you:

Location

> 4.1 Apps that do not notify and obtain user consent before collecting, transmitting, or using location data will be rejected
>
> 4.2 Apps that use location-based APIs for automatic or autonomous control of vehicles, aircraft, or other devices will be rejected
>
> 4.3 Apps that use location-based APIs for dispatch, fleet management, or emergency services will be rejected
>
> 4.4 Location data can only be used when directly relevant to the features and services provided by the App to the user or to support
>   approved advertising uses
>
> Privacy
>
> 17.1 Apps cannot transmit data about a user without obtaining the user's prior permission and providing the user with access to
>   information about how and where the data will be used
>
> 17.2 Apps that require users to share personal information, such as email address and date of birth, in order to function will be rejected
>
> 17.3 Apps that target minors for data collection will be rejected

Independent of what the guideline says, you should be mindful of your users privacy. As long as you don't pin the information you collect to individual users, I guess you might be fine. 
Regarding location data, the guideline states you can't collect for analytical purposes if it is not relevant to the app's usage. However, it is referring to the gps data. You can obtain location for analytical purposes through network access information.